# How to validate radio buttons with a input field inside it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button, jquery-validate

So I have these radio buttons that a user can select and then I need a text input inside of it. How can I validate these inputs so that they are required to select a radio option, and if it is one of the first two, make sure they fill out the text inputs? I assume I need to use the jquery.validator.addMethod somehow, but i'm really lost on what I need to do. I'd really appreciate some help. Thanks so much!

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.15.1/additional-methods.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.15.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<div id="itemPricing" class="clearfix">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12" form-group>
      <label for="itemPricing" class="required">Pricing</label>
      <span id="helpBlock" class="help-block">Select how you want pricing to display on your website.</span>
    </div>
    <!-- Regular Price -->
    <div class="col-sm-12 form-group">
      <div class="form-inline radio-input-group">
        <div class="radio">
          <input type="radio" class="height-initial" name="pricingOptions" id="regularPrice" value="">
          <label for="regularPrice" class="required">Regular Price</label>
        </div>
        <div class="input-group">
          <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
          <input type="text" class="form-control money" id="productPrice" name="productPrice">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-inline radio-input-group">
        <div class="radio">
          <input type="radio" class="height-initial" name="pricingOptions" id="salePrice" value="">
          <label for="salePrice" class="required">Sale Price</label>
        </div>
        <div class="input-group">
          <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
          <input type="text" class="form-control money" id="productPrice" name="productPrice">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-inline radio-input-group">
        <div class="radio">
          <input type="radio" class="height-initial" name="pricingOptions" id="emailPrice" value="">
          <label for="emailPrice" class="required">Email for Price</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- end itemPricing -->
  
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success save ladda-button" data-style="zoom-in">Save</button>
```

Comment: **Client side** validation (js/html...) will never be good enough, it's easily bypassed with simple inspect element fiddling. If you really want to validate your client's input you need to do that on the **Server side** (php/node/ruby...)

Comment: @Mihailo I'm handing this off to a developer who will build the form in asp.net so I'll bring this up. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, skipping server side validation is not an option, but you get a better user experience if you also validate on the client side too. Waiting for the round trip to the server before the user becomes aware of the problem is a sure way to piss the user off. The radio buttons can have `onChange` handlers that check to see if the button is selected and set the required status of the textbox accordingly.